# UIWebView load html file from bundle, and provide file with information?

Tags: html, objective-c, uiwebview, error-handling

I'm interested in replicating Mobile Safari's "Cannot Open Page" StandardError page.

In order to do that, I've been researching how mobile safari handle's an error when loading a page and opens the html file located in the application bundle.

In that bundle, the file: StandardError.html is loaded and produces an error while showing the mobile safari icon. The one thing that I'm having trouble with is understanding how the error is passed from the webview to the html file.

In the body of the html file, there is a variable with %@.  I'm assuming that the %@ indicates where Apple provides the error that caused the webview to fail loading.  What I want to know is how to provide the title and error to an html file, similar to the StandardError.html file found in Mobile Safari's application bundle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A `UIWebView` can load HTML from a string so you can do this:

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"StandardError" ofType:@"html"];
NSString* errorHTML = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:errorHTML, weberror.localizedDescription];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Or something like that.

Comment: What's not working Jasmine? The above code was only an example of the approach. For example 'weberror' is undefined and used to suggest an error object you might have in your app.